# Plotting model coefficients of ZINB models using dotwhisker

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the coefficients of three zero-inflated negative binomial models.

My data looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  Park              Week       Coy_Season Reports_per_week Number_AC Reports_month_pri~ Number_4w_AC Year_numeric
  <chr>             <date>     <chr>                 <dbl>     <int>              <dbl>        <int>        <dbl>
1 14st NE - Covent~ 2018-04-29 1                         0         0                  0            0            1
2 14st NE - Covent~ 2018-05-06 2                         0         0                  0            0            1
3 Airways Park      2021-07-18 2                         3         0                  0            0            4
4 Aspen Heights     2021-03-28 1                         2        12                  0            0            4
5 Aspen Heights     2021-05-09 2                         0        13                  0            0            4
```

> 

Where Coy_Season vary between 1-3 and Year_numeric varies between 1-4.

```
zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.1 <- glmmTMB(Reports_per_week ~ (1|Park) + Reports_month_prior,
                                 ziformula = ~ Reports_month_prior + Number_4w_AC + (1|Park) 
                                 + Year_numeric + factor(Coy_Season),
                                 data = Reports_per_park_per_week_3,
                                 family = nbinom2, na.action = "na.fail")

zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.2 <- glmmTMB(Reports_per_week ~ (1|Park) + Reports_month_prior + Year_numeric,
                                   ziformula = ~ Reports_month_prior + Number_4w_AC + (1|Park) 
                                   + Year_numeric + factor(Coy_Season),
                                   data = Reports_per_park_per_week_3,
                                   family = nbinom2, na.action = "na.fail")

zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.3 <- glmmTMB(Reports_per_week ~ (1|Park) + Reports_month_prior + Number_4w_AC,
                                   ziformula = ~ Reports_month_prior + Number_4w_AC + (1|Park) 
                                   + Year_numeric + factor(Coy_Season),
                                   data = Reports_per_park_per_week_3,
                                   family = nbinom2, na.action = "na.fail")
library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)
library(dotwhisker)

dwplot(list(zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.1, zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.2, zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.3),
       effects = "fixed")
```

The resulting plot merges my coefficients from my conditional model and my zero-inflated model when a variable is present in both models, which is incorrect. How can I make my dwplot model the variables in my conditional models independently from those in my zero-inflated models (one coefficient for each conditional model, and one coefficient for each ZI model)?

Comment: could we please have a [mcve]?  My general strategy in these cases is to use `purrr::map_dfr(list(m1=mod1, m2=mod2, m3=mod3), tidy, effects = "fixed", .id = "model")`; manipulate the components of the resulting model frame as desired with tidyverse or base-R tools; and then either pass the result to `dwplot()` or (more usually) build my own `ggplot` with `geom_pointrange()` ...

Comment: I tried to apply the first part of your solution by doing:
purrr::map_dfr(list(m1=zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.1, m2=zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.2,
                    m3=zero.infl.neg.bin.mod.3), tidy, effects = "fixed",
               .id = "model").
But I get the following error: Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'tidy' not found. How can I fix it? Am I missing a package?

Comment: did you forget to load `broom.mixed`?

Comment: I did, thank you! That worked, but how do I manipulate the components of the resulting model frame so that I can include both the cond component and the zi component in my graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load packages:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(broom.mixed)
library(tidyverse)
library(dotwhisker)
theme_set(theme_bw())
```

Fit models (reproducible example):

```r
m1 <- glmmTMB(count ~ spp + mined + (1|site),
               zi=~spp + mined,
              family=nbinom2, data=Salamanders)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . - (1|site))
```

Put together combined, tidied results:

```r
tt <- (list(with_RE = m1, no_RE = m2)
  %>% purrr::map_dfr(tidy, effects = "fixed", conf.int = TRUE,
                     .id = "model")
  %>% select(model, component, term, estimate, conf.low, conf.high)
  ## drop conditional intercept term (not interesting)
  %>% filter(!(term == "(Intercept)" & component == "cond"))
  ## create new 'term' that combines component and term
  %>% mutate(term_orig = term,
             term = forcats::fct_inorder(paste(term, component, sep = "_")))
)
```

Now that the `term` values are unique, this can be plugged into `dwplot`:

```r
dwplot(tt)
```

[image: dot-whisker plot 1]

Or use `ggplot` + `geom_pointrange` for more flexibility:

```r
(ggplot(tt)
  + aes(x = estimate, xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high, y = term_orig)
  + geom_pointrange(aes(colour = model),
                    position = position_dodge(width = 0.25))
  + facet_wrap(~component, scale = "free_x")
)
```

[image: faceted dot-whisker plot]